# How to retrieve dicts from a list of dicts using wildcard key value

Tags: python

I have a large list of dictionaries, each dict has a key:value as normal. I want to grab all dicts that a match a particular wildcard key value for the name key in the example below.

For example, if the values of the name keys below are in the format `A_B_C_D` (e.g. `John_Michael_Joseph_Smith`), how would I grab all dicts searching for name values of format `A*D` (e.g. `John*Smith`?) Or format `A_B*` (e.g. `John_Michael*`) etc?

```
mylist=[{id:value,name:value,parent:value},
        {id:value,name:value,parent:value},
        {id:value,name:value,parent:value}...]
```

Comment: Can you give a real example of the dict you're using, not just a description of its format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patterns appear to use UNIX filename patterns; `*` matching any number of characters. You can use the [`fnmatch.fnmatch()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) to produce a filter:

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch('John_Michael_Joseph_Smith', 'John*Smith')
True
>>> fnmatch('John_Michael_Joseph_Smith', 'John_Michael*')
True
```

You could use the filter in a list comprehension to produce a new list of matching dictionaries, testing each `dictionary['name']` value against the pattern:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def namesearch(pattern, dictionaries):
    return [d for d in dictionaries if fnmatch(d['name'], pattern)]
```

Here `namesearch` returns a list dictionaries whose `'name'` value matches the given pattern:

```
matched = namesearch('John*Smith', mylist)
```

Comment: I'm a bit slow here.. is 'dictionaries' really mylist? I want to pass in large list of dicts.. so the code would look like:from fnmatch import fnmatch

    def namesearch(John*Smith, mylist):
        return [d for d in mylist if fnmatch(d['name'], John*Smith)]

Comment: @AP70: I've added a sample use; `dictionaries` is just a parameter in the function. You can pass in your list (which you named `mylist`) as that parameter.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it. So pattern in your example would be 'John*Smith' as a string? Is that correct?

Comment: @AP70: exactly; the function will return all dictionaries in `mylist` whose `name` value match that pattern.

Comment: Thank you Martijn, really appreciate the lesson.